# How to write a small (socket) server in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I saw this in some official iOS apps, so I know it's possible and permitted.

I want to write a small socket server in iOS that some other application, that I will write for a desktop machine, can connect to and read data from.

Anyone did something like this and can help me with some clues or knows a good starting point ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should read the [Stream Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000188-SW1), the [WiTap](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html) sample, and many other Programming Guides, Samples and Documentation in Apple's Doc, you will find everything there (including detailed explanations and code)

If you simply go to the home page of iOS SDK documentation and go in the "Networking & Internet Topics" you have plenty of resources too, including the [Network & Internet Starting Point](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Networking_iPhone/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007301) guide and much more.

Comment: I don;t know why this didn't show up in Google... I believe I should of thought to also look there... WiTap example seems exactly what I was needing and Stream Programming Guide looks like it could feel any void that I might encounter on my way. Thank you very much ;)

Comment: Except ... Apple's docs are completly missing the "server" part of this. The links provided are all dead now too (Apple keeps deleting their docs :( )

Comment: WiTap is great example.