# Can iOS detect and pair to an Android devices over bluetooth?

Tags: android, objective-c, bluetooth, multipeer-connectivity

I am looking to develop an iOS and Android application which will allow users to chat to each other via bluetooth however I am unsure if this is possible with Apple Restrictions.

Currently I have written a test iOS app using Multipeer Connectivity Framework which can discover other iOS devices which has my app and connect, but I am unsure of the best practice to do the same for iOS -> Android or vice versa.

Thanks Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. WiFi connection may be your best bet.

See here:

[Transfer data between iOS and Android via Bluetooth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884705/transfer-data-between-ios-and-android-via-bluetooth)