# Apple documentation about transferring data between iOS and Android via Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

Can anyone give the link about Apple has restrictions that prevent connecting an Android phone to an iPhone over Bluetooth.

Comment: This has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884705/transfer-data-between-ios-and-android-via-bluetooth

Comment: I know that it is not possible, I need apple documentation to show to my client that it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then show your client this: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US
and tell him that simply it isn't in apple's bluetooth profiles.