# How to share files with all other devices from my iOS device through application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, file-transfer

I want to share files/data from my iOS app to other devices (ios and android), which have the application installed, through wireless communication. Is it possible? Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transfer data between iOS and Android via Bluetooth?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884705/transfer-data-between-ios-and-android-via-bluetooth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iBeacon is not for file sharing, for more information check [this link](https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/)

And about file sharing between **Android** and **iOS** via **Bluetooth** it has asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884705/transfer-data-between-ios-and-android-via-bluetooth)

But you can write an **App** that enables file sharing between iOS devices quite simple. Check [MultiPeer Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html)

Also there are new technologies but I don't have enough information about them.