# Is it possible to establish a Bluetooth connection between iPhone and Android devices?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to know if this is possible. Has anyone done this before?

I've searched online, but I haven't seen any working examples.

This answer was posted back in September 2013, but I was wondering if anything has changed since then: [Apple has restrictions that prevent this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18984325/5294765)

Comment: Can you tell us what research/work you've done so far?

Comment: As long as both devices support Bluetooth Low Energy then you can write apps for both sides that communicate via BLE, but there is no "out of the box" connectivity

Comment: I've worked on BLE applications for that, no problems.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge,
Apple prevent to connecting with another devices(Android) via bluetooth.
but I have a another supplementary way to connect iPhone and Android phone using WiFi with an app that is available on AppStore and PlayStore.
I'm Using `Xender` app to connect. `Xender` is an app that provide connection between iPhone and Android via WiFi.
hope it may help you.