# Is it possible to create a cross-platform, OFFLINE mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

I mean the simplest possible scenario: one of users starts the app in host mode, and others are in client mode, they can search for nearby hosts (up to 2-3 meters distance) and join selected host and then exchange data with the host. It should work cross platform.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: offline without internet but online with bluetooth, yes, offline with everything then no

Comment: Bluetooth does not allow for cross-platform communication. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884705/transfer-data-between-ios-and-android-via-bluetooth Is there another option?

Comment: BTLE can do it... hardware permitting

Answer (score 0):

yes it possible
use XAMARIN with Visual Studio 
(code in c#)

Answer (score 0):

There are already such apps like [Firechat](https://www.opengarden.com/firechat.html), [Hood](http://www.meshine.eu/), [Jott](http://jott.com/) or [YO!](http://www.wave.io/apps/yo/) (ok, the last one uses Wifi).