# Cross-platform method to receive files directly from another device?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone, cross-platform, file-transfer

I need to be able to receive an image from a member of the public's phone. The solution needs to be cross platform. On the receiving end, we will have a purpose built app for Android, IOS, and Windows. We have no control over the sender's device, and we have to consider all combinations of the sender's and receiver's device, e.g. Android to IOS, IOS to Windows etc.

I couldn't find this question asked before on Stack Overflow. I've looked into Bluetooth, NFC, Wifi direct etc. and there seems to be no standard and cross platform way to share files (in my case pictures) between Android, IOS and Windows phones without the use of a third party app.

I've thought about using email or a web-form (the image could then be pushed to our apps from our server). But this is not a good solution.

Is there a cross-platform method or API to receive files directly from another device?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting

Comment: I've tried to improve the wording of my question. I am looking for a programming solution.

Comment: For reference:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884705/transfer-data-between-ios-and-android-via-bluetooth